# SQL Group By for two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have two tables, one with customer information and the other with order information. I am trying to put together a merged table that gives me the customer info and adds a column that counts total orders.

I am currently writing my query similar like this:

```
SELECT 
    C.PrimaryKey,
    C.ClientNumber,
    COUNT(O.Orders) AS 'Number of Orders'
FROM
    ClientInfo C
JOIN 
    Orders O ON O.PrimaryKey=C.PrimaryKey
GROUP BY 
    C.ClientNumber
```

I have ran different variances of the above query and get 1 of 2 results;

- An error 'is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause'
- Or  an incorrect output that counts each order as its own row instead of counting totals in one column:

| ClientNumber | Total Orders |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1 |
| 1234 | 1 |
| 1234 | 1 |
| 5678 | 1 |
| 5678 | 1 |
| 5678 | 1 |

Ideally, my output would look like this:

| ClientNumber | Total Orders |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 3 |
| 5678 | 3 |

Comment: Why are you grouping by the column you are aggregating? You `GROUP BY` the columns expressions you *aren't* aggregating.

Comment: Also, your `JOIN` is missing the `ON` keyword for your `ON` clause.

Comment: You also won't want to be joining on the primary key of both tables. It would help to provide the full table structure (I'm guessing that the orders table has a ClientNumber?)

Comment: "invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause" is one of the clearest messages in SQL Server. You cannot select a column in a grouping query unless it is either aggregated in a function or it is in the `GROUP BY`

Comment: I had to change the query to something basic due to security reasons with my table names - when i edited i just forgot the ON keyword but it is in my actual query. I apologize

Comment: So provide a valid and meaningful example, @TaylorD98 . YOur query isn't valid and doesn't make sense as, again, you're trying to group *and* aggregate the same column and *not* do either on the other 2. Grouping and aggregating *should* be mutually exclusive.

Comment: i have also tried to group by different columns as i stated above and it is still giving  me the same error. that is what i am asking lol

Comment: If you `GROUP BY` the 2 columns you *aren't* aggregating, the error goes away; have you tried that?

Comment: Like I said it's quite clear. You can do `GROUP BY C.PrimaryKey, C.ClientNumber` or you can remove those columns from the `SELECT`. No you haven't tried that because you wouldn't have got an error. Please show what you *actually* tried, as this will solve what you have shown so far.

Comment: Yes, as i stated above i have tried that and it still gives the same error.

Comment: You should not include the primary key in select. As the primary key is a unique key for each row. And `group by` the other column.

Comment: What is the column in the order table that stores the primary key **of the customer** (ie the foreign key to customer)? Your query suggests that it's the primary key of the order table, but that makes no sense. Please explain.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know that PK has nothing to do with question. But including PK in `select` means you need to include it in `group by` which means that the `group by` wont work. And looking on desired results it doesn't include the PK.

Comment: @TaylorD98 what you posted is simply invalid SQL. Instead of insisting about other people's decisions that *won't* change how databases work, post what you actually want to achieve: original data, expected output. There's no `PrimaryKey` column in your output, so why do you insist on adding it? You simply can't have that column in there. And why use that confusing name? ID, CustomerID, OrderID are meaningful. `PrimaryKey` is not.

Comment: @Shmiel sorry, I just realized that the OP used `PrimaryKey` as a column name. Bad naming will make  it harder to explain what's wrong with this query

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos since you are unable to read what i have clearly stated, this is just an example query and output because i am unable to share actual column names or output due to my security clearance at my job. I did the best i could to ask the question with what i could share.

Comment: Is the column you call `PrimaryKey` a foreign key? What column is a PK? And what is a FK?

Comment: @TaylorD98 no security clearance prevents you from posting valid code or a meaningful example. Don't assume the people telling you this is wrong don't have 20 years of DB experience - each. Even if you believe we have something against you, it's the *database* you have to persuade.

Comment: @TaylorD98 you're the one getting a syntax error, not us. You can easily create an example. Post the CREATE TABLE schemas and INSERT statements with the data you want, and we'll write the correct query, which btw is `SELECT 
C.ClientNumber,
COUNT(O.Orders) AS 'Number of Orders'
FROM
ClientInfo C
JOIN Orders O ON O.ClientID=C.ClientID
GROUP BY C.ClientNumber`. I *seriously* doubt the primary key for your clients is the same as the primary key for your orders. Most likely you matched the wrong columns.

Comment: I have never used dbfiddle, i'm sorry. I have only been working with SQL for a few months and am trying my best. This is the first question (and last) i have ever asked and tried to write it without compromising work data and clearly messed up. It would be nice if next time people were kind instead of talking down to me. Many people are still learning and doing the best they can.

Comment: You're the one talking down and insulting people, saying they didn't read the question or that it's clear when it's clearly not working and the desired output doesn't contain the data you say you want. The 3 answers posted show two completely different queries with different results based on assumptions about what you want. Either of them could be true. Or *all* of them, if `PrimaryKey` and `ClientNumber` are 1:1

Comment: As to security: It is hard to imagine that table and columns names are top secret. Or is it something like `select a.attack_id, a.attack_date, count(b.bomb_id) as "number of bombs" from my_intended_terror_attacks a join bombs b on b.attack_id = a.attack_id group by a.attack_id` maybe? In other words: I think you are carrying the security idea a tad to far :-)

Comment: I just started working at my job and am just doing what they tell me. I am sorry

Comment: Well, don't worry. We are all developers here, so we are looking for precise requests. When we tell you there is something amiss in your sample query, this is nothing personal. It is just that we try to understand the issue in detail.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner thank you for your kindness. I am trying my best

Comment: Look, we're happy to help and we're not trying to be unkind, it's just hard if we don't understand and the goalposts keep moving. So when I said you can't have tried adding the column, it's because we could all see that it didn't make sense otherwise, but you kept insisting you tried it. But because we couldn't see the actual code you tried, we couldn't get a handle on it. So pretty please, in future questions, if you need to obfuscate your query due to security, maybe just change the names to something else, but leave the rest of it more closely to the actual query you are trying.

Answer (score 2):

In trying to covert your original query to a simple sample query, you have mutilated it. It makes no sense to join two tables an their respective primary key. You want to join on a foreign key instead.

It seems you want to count orders per client. I suggest you count your orders per client and join this to the client table. Thus you can show all columns of the client table. (The same should be possible by joining both tables and grouping by the client table's primary key, but SQL Server doesn't support this standard SQL feature, so you would have to put all client info columns you want to select in the `GROUP BY` clause, if you joined first and aggregated then.)

```
SELECT 
  c.clientinfo_id,
  c.clientnumber,
  o.number_of_orders
FROM clientinfo c
JOIN 
(
  SELECT clientinfo_id, COUNT(orders) AS number_of_orders
  FROM orders
  GROUP BY clientinfo_id
) o ON o.clientinfo_id = c.clientinfo_id
ORDER BY c.clientinfo_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your FK relation is Order.ForeignKey = ClientInfo.PrimaryKey, here is an example of working query:

```
SELECT 
  C.PrimaryKey
, C.ClientNumber,
, COALESCE(O.Count,0) AS [Number of Orders]
FROM ClientInfo C
LEFT JOIN 
(
   SELECT 
     O.ForeignKey
   , COUNT(*) AS Count
   FROM Orders O 
   GROUP BY O.ForeignKey
) O ON O.ForeginKey = C.PrimaryKey
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question/query is unclear, so this suggested query is based on muscle memory:

```
SELECT 
  C.PrimaryKey,
  C.ClientNumber,
  COUNT(O.Orders) AS 'Number of Orders'
FROM ClientInfo C
JOIN Orders O ON O.ClientInfoPrimaryKey=C.PrimaryKey
GROUP BY C.PrimaryKey, C.ClientNumber
```

The changes are:

1. change `O.PrimaryKey=C.PrimaryKey` to `O.ClientInfoPrimaryKey=C.PrimaryKey`. You haven't told us what the name of the foreign key to customer in the orders table is, so I guessed it might be `ClientInfoPrimaryKey` - correct as necessary.
2. changed to group by `C.PrimaryKey, C.ClientNumber` - all non-aggregated columns

Comment: Thank you for your help. Sorry it was a bit unclear, i am trying my best

Comment: @TaylorD98 that's what Charlieface proposed 25 minutes earlier but you dismissed this, insisting you've tried this.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i did try this and it did not work, i was just saying thank you to somebody who clearly and kindly gave me an answer. Please just leave me alone